# Float value parsing in java

Tags: java, floating-point-conversion

When I am doing this

```
value = Float.parseFloat("5555998.558f");

System.out.println("Value: " + value);
```

It gives me result `5555998.5` rather than `5555998.558` 
I am using the variable value for some calculation. And I need the exact value i.e. `5555998.558`

How to overcome this?

Comment: Why are you using a float rather than a double?

Comment: Why are you using a primitive floating-point data type instead of `BigDecimal`?

Comment: the value is coming form a textfield thats why I am doing this.

Comment: @user3203455: "the value is coming from a textfield" doesn't explain why you're using `float` instead of either `double` or `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `float` value at that high value has a precision of only 0.5, so Java parsed it to the closest `float` value it could = `5555998.5`, and that's what was printed.

To see the difference between the 2 closest values at that magnitude, use [`Math.ulp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-) (unit in the last place):

```
String s = "5555998.558f";
float value = Float.parseFloat(s);
System.out.println(value);
System.out.println(Math.ulp(value));
```

This prints

```
5555998.5
0.5
```

You can use a `double` which has much better precision:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(Math.ulp(d));
```

This prints

```
5555998.558
9.313225746154785E-10
```

Interestingly, `Double.parseDouble` doesn't seem to mind the `f` on the end.  [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) converts the `String` into a `double` "as performed by the valueOf method of class Double".  And [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) states:

> FloatValue:
>
> - Signopt NaN
> - Signopt Infinity
> - Signopt FloatingPointLiteral
> - Signopt HexFloatingPointLiteral
> - SignedInteger

This method will take a `String` as if it were a Java numeric literal, which Java supports with a `f` on the end to indicate a floating-point literal.

Comment: ... or better, BigDecimal which will preserve the exact decimal value entered.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, `BigDecimal` will have the arbitrary precision.  But `new BigDecimal("5555998.558f")` throws a `NumberFormatException` because the `f` is present.  Now I'm curious as to why `Float.parseFloat` and `Double.parseDouble` seem to ignore the `f` in the string.

Comment: I'm surprised at that too, although it's documented in `Float.valueOf`. I guess the best solution will depend on why the `f` is there at all, and what the OP really wants to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

`BigDecimal` is probably your best bet for exact decimal representations.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("5555998.558");
```

It's immutable, so every operation you do to it will result in you creating a new `BigDecimal` instance, but its precision is also likely what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this :

```
Double value = Double.valueOf("5555998.558f");
System.out.println("Value: " + value);
```

output :

```
Value: 5555998.558
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
float: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers. This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform.

So use BigDecimal and you'll have no problem.